# ¿Cómo modificar un textView en android a través de un botón?

Tags: android, botón, textview

Como Puedo modificar un text View desde un boton, ejemplo una calculadora que cuando le das al cero debe poner cero en pantalla osea en el text view.

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio Maria Alexanda!, es bueno tenerte aquí, te sugiero leer [ask] que te brinda información para realizar tu pregunta, para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas buenas respuestas. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Saludos!!!

Comment: Has intentado algo hasta ahora y si lo has intentado por favor agrega el código a la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

En el `onCreate` de tu `Activity` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
final TextView label = (Label) findViewById(R.id.label_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Si quieres poner el mismo valor que el texto del botón
        label.setText(v.getText());
        //Si quieres agregarle al valor del texto del Label el texto del botón
        // label.setText(label.getText()+v.getText());
        //Si quieres ponerle un texto predeterminado "0"
        // label.setText("0");
        //Si quieres agregarle un texto predeterminado "0"
        // label.setText(label.getText()+"0");
    }
});
```

Comment: Reemplaza **button_id** y **label_id** por tus respectivos identificadores (el del botón y el del textView)